# mLab REST API - Query by string

Tags: rest, api, mlab

I recently set up a new database/collection with a simple Json document on mLab. I enabled the data API and am experimenting with filtering the results via the query parameter. The complete document is too large to host within my app, unfortunately.

Here is what the document looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "5c59f496hv7ec06f4f560f4c"
    },
    "songs": [
        {
            "title": "title 1",
            "artist": "musician 1",
            "album": "fake album",
            "minsec": "2:04",
            "songid": "11100"
        },
        {
            "title": "fake title",
            "artist": "musician 1",
            "album": "album 2",
            "minsec": "2:57",
            "songid": "11102"
        },
        {
            "title": "title 3",
            "artist": "musician 2",
            "album": "album 3",
            "minsec": "3:06",
            "songid": "11078"
        },
        {
            "title": "title 4",
            "artist": "fake musician",
            "album": "album 4",
            "minsec": "2:28",
            "songid": "11103"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would love to be able to search the document with a string that would return any object from the array that has a value that includes that string. For example, searching for 'fake' which would return the first, second and fourth object with the following url:

```
https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/<my-db>/collections/<my-collection>?q=fake&apiKey=<my-apikey>
```

It appears that mLab's data API only processes queries("q=") using json notation, and even knowing that I still can't figure out how to return anything other than an empty array or a

"Could not parse JSON parameter, please double-check syntax and encoding"

error.

Thanks for any help you guys can offer!

**Update** I inserted each song object as an individual document, rather than a single large document, and can filter them using using specific queries...still unsure of how to implement a more wildcard solution to filtering results with values that include/contain the query.

For anyone seeking assistance with mlab related issues, I would suggest reaching out to their very helpful support team.

**Final Update** I figured out how to use regex to filter my results satisfactorily:

`{$regex: '(?i).*<string>.*'}`

Answer (score 0):

if using the mlab data API, use regex to filter the results:

`https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/<my-db>/collections/<my-collection>?apiKey=<my-apikey>&q={'<key>':$regex:'(?i).*<value>.*'}`

the i option turns case sensitivity off.